# Django Cache-control header: Why isn't Chrome caching this resource?

Tags: django, google-chrome, caching, http-headers, browser

I have decorated a Django view with `cache_control` as follows:

```
@cache_control(
    private=True,
    max_age=5 * 60,  # 5 minutes
)
def my_view(req):
    …
```

When I try it with the local test server, it works as expected: subsequent page views in Chrome use the cached resource and don't make a request. When deployed in production, though, Chrome seems to ignore the `Cache-control` header and makes a new request every time I hit that page.

Here's the full list of headers that the production server responds with:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=300
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:13135
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 22 Jan 2014 20:39:29 GMT
P3P:CP="IDC CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"
Server:nginx/1.4.1
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=87y26bT5uPmyA9wt51N7m4blyqBH5nSo; expires=Wed, 21-Jan-2015 20:39:29 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Vary:Cookie,Accept-Encoding
```

What could be going wrong? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: it was a combination of Google Analytics' cookie and the `Vary:Cookie` header (set by Django's `SessionMiddleware`). Analytics' cookie changes with each request, but since `ga.js` doesn't load when working on `localhost`, the problem only showed up in production.